# $A^T A$ always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying projections and least squares chapter and I got a question.

there is
\begin{eqnarray} 
A^TA\hat{x}&=&A^Tb \\
\hat{x}&=&(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb \\
\end{eqnarray}

but $A^TA$ isn't always invertible. how can i understand this explanation?

Comment: nope i think this is general situation for solving least square problem

Comment: How about including more context, including exactly the way the name $A$ was introduced and other details leading up to these equations.

Comment: If A is not invertible $(A^TA)^{-1}$ won't exist.

Comment: @Jeanba not necessarily.  It is not given that $A$ is a square matrix.  It is possible for $A$ to not have been invertible due to it being non-square but still be of full rank and $A^TA$ winding up being full rank as well.  *Especially* considering the context and least squares method is generally only ever used for overdetermined systems.

Comment: @JMoravitz well spotted! thanks for taking the time to reply to my comment!

Comment: $A^TA$ is invertible it and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. In the case of projections, the columns of $A$ are usually taken to form a basis of the space onto which you’re projecting, so the condition is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that we are trying to find a line of best fit to $n$ data points in the plane, $(x_1,y_1),\cdots,(x_n,y_n)$.

Typically in this situation, $$A=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} x_1& 1\\x_2&1\\ \vdots &\vdots \\x_n&1\end{array}\right]$$

Provided that there are at least two distinct values among the $x_i$, the matrix $A^T \cdot A$ will in fact be an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix (because $A$ will be of rank $2$.). This covers nearly all cases of practical application of least squares.  (If $n=1$, trying to use least squares is silly--there is only one point. If all $x$s are the equal, then clearly the fitting line is a vertical line.)